# Learning to use OOP documentation

Tags: java, android, oop, codeigniter, yii

I'm just learning android and java.

I find that I'm having difficulty in using the documentation. They all look gibberish. Are there any tips and tricks on how to use any OOP documentations?

So far I've used the following documentations without difficulty before:

PHP, Jquery, CodeIgniter

I find difficulty in the following documentations:

Yii, Android

Are there some techniques in reading OOP documentations?

Comment: If you have some experience with JavaDocs, then Android docs should be easy for you.

Comment: Nope, never had experience with JavaDocs

Comment: My problem with the docs (Android) was understanding how classes and packages are organized. I wouldn't have been able to learn this without following some books and tutorials. From then on, practice was the best teacher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't specific to object oriented programming, but you've encountered the difference between a tutorial and a reference.

A tutorial shows you how to use the product or application.  A reference shows you all of the features of the product or application.  A tutorial looks at the product or application from the outside.  A reference looks at the product or application from the inside.

When you're first learning about something, like Android or Yii, you need a tutorial.  Later, after you have some experience with the product or application, a reference is more understandable.  You know more about how the pieces of the product or application fit together.

Unfortunately, you sometimes come across a tutorial that assumes too much product or application knowledge.  Especially in the open source world.